# Proving This Theorem on Independence

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request

I'm trying to find a good resource for proving the following theorem, stated in Shreve's "Stochastic Calculus for Finance II," p. 73:

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space, and let
>   $\mathcal{G}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$.  Suppose the
>   random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are $\mathcal{G}$-measurable and the
>   random variables $Y_1,\ldots,Y_m$ are independent of $\mathcal{G}$. 
>   Let $f = f(x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_m)$ be measurable and define 
>   $$
>  g(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = E(f(x_1,\ldots,x_n, Y_1,\ldots,Y_m)). 
> $$ 
>   Then 
>   $$
> E(f(X_1,\ldots,X_n,Y_1,\ldots,Y_m) \mid \mathcal{G}) = g(X_1,\ldots,X_n). 
> $$

Answer (score 1):

See, for example, *Foundations of Modern Probability* by O. Kallenberg; specifically Lemma 3.11 on page 52 of the Second Edition. Kallenberg deduces the result from Fubini's theorem.

Alternatively, one can note that the result is trivial if $f$ factors as $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_m)=f_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\cdot f_2(y_1,\ldots,y_m)$, and the general case then follows by a monotone class argument.